# List is not shown when extending MapActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with showing a list.

I have an activity that extends a `MapActivity` and inside I have a `listView` Object. When the activity extends the `ListActivity` everything works fine. But when it extends the `MapActivity` the `ListView` is not shown. I found out, that the `getView()` is not called. Maybe anyone of you can have a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.event_list);

    // lock the screen orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    eventList = EventHandler.getInstance(this).getEventList();

    adapter = new EventAdapter(this, R.layout.event_item,
            R.id.event_item_title, eventList);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            BLAEvent selectedEvent = eventList.get(position);

            if (selectedEvent.getType() == BLAEvent.TYPE_MESSAGE)
                Utils.showCustomMessageDialog((Activity) getBaseContext(),
                        selectedEvent);
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.putExtra("currentEventId", eventList.get(position)
                        .getId());


                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();


            }

        }
    });


    // refreshList
    viewLog = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getEventList();
            handler.postDelayed(viewLog, 3000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(viewLog);

}

/** The return res. */
private final Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d("EventListSize in returnRes", "" + eventList.size());
        if (eventList != null && eventList.size() > 0) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++)
                adapter.add(eventList.get(i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

/**
 * Gets the log.
 * 
 * @return the log
 */
private void getEventList() {

    try {
        eventList.clear();

        switch (currentEventFilter) {
        case 1:// EVENTS
            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList(BLAEvent.TYPE_REPORT));

            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList(BLAEvent.TYPE_ALERT));
            break;

        case 2:// REQUEST
            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList(BLAEvent.TYPE_REQUEST));
            break;

        case 3:// MESSAGES
            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList(BLAEvent.TYPE_MESSAGE));
            break;

        case 4: // ALL
            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList());
            break;

        default:
            eventList.addAll(EventHandler.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                    .getEventList());

            break;
        }
        Log.d("EventListSize", "" + eventList.size());
        Log.i("REFREHS LIST", "Refreshing list...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
```

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_logo">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonGeneric.Short"
        android:visibility="gone"></Button>
    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonGeneric.Long"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/eventlist_button_newreport"
        android:onClick="onClickNewReport" android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>



</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventlist_filtername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Showing all items"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:text="@string/eventlist_no_reports" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I am not sure if it is possible to incorporate both at the same time. As both classes (Map, List) inherit from activity you can do one of them. And also there is no mapview in your XML file, so I am a little bit confused why you want to use MapActivity.

Answer (score 0):

`MapActivity` is used to show Maps.

`ListActivity` is used to display a list.

They are different things, don't mix them up like that.